# fcntl() give IO when locking file on NFS share

Tags: c++, c, c++11, locking, nfs

I was trying to lock a file in NFS so did I tried the following,first I've gone with CLI

```
exec 80>lock.file
echo "testwrite" > &80
flock -s 80 [IO error]
```

Then I've found `flock` is not much in case of locking file in NFS so I planned to go `lockf` and I have written the following code

```
  void write_lock(string path)
    {
        int fd;
        int error;

        fd = open(path.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0664);
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror("open");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        // if len is zero, lock all bytes
        error = lockf(fd, F_LOCK, 0);
        if (error == 0){
            printf("%#x: lock succeeds!\n", getpid());
            cout<<"locked"<<endl;

            }
        else
        {
            perror("lockf");

        }

        sleep(1);
        lockf(fd, F_ULOCK, 0);
        cout<<"unlocked"<<endl;
        close(fd);
  }
```

nothing wrong with the code it compiles ans lock the file when i ran it locally,but when I run in the mounted path 'a.out "filename"' I end up in same IO error.and I fired `tshark` to sniff the reply message, It says the below when I did apply lock(shared/exclusive)

```
NFS 190 V3 ACCESS Reply (Call In 2092), [Access Denied: XE], [Allowed: RD MD XT] //Access Denied for even newly created file already exist one and for every lock it says the same
```

Can anyone tell me what went wrong I stuck here, if I found where it cause the problem I will write the code in c++11  to get through it..yet I have a hard time with it

Comment: is it possible to lock a file using NFS?

Comment: NFS version 4 has locking.

Comment: @Barmar but i suffer with v3 unfortunately i gotta deal with them

Comment: OK, NLM provides locking support there, so it should work. It looks like maybe it's a permissions problem?

Comment: it doesn't seems to be i could create,write and delete,so ain't sure it has to deal with any permission for locking..

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22044/correct-locking-in-shell-scripts

Comment: @Fabio i appreciate you dropped some info its good but they have been using 'lockrun' seems to be a tool to get around with locks..in my case i was trying to figure out why the initial lock itself getting failed with IO